# SagePay Direct Payment Integration C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, e-commerce, opayo

I am trying to implement a credit card payment solution on my website using SagePay, where I can take payment on my website. I am using ASP.NET Web forms and C#. Here is my code:

```
var objSagePay = new SagePayIntegration();
var request = objSagePay.DirectPaymentRequest();

if ((request != null)) {
    request.Vendor = "testVendor";
    request.CardHolder = "Customer Name";
    request.CardNumber = "4900000000000";
    request.CardType = CardType.VISA;
    request.ExpiryDate = "0119";
    request.Cv2 = "123";
    request.Currency = "GBP";
    request.Amount = 10.0;
    request.BillingAddress1 = "Test Address 1";
    request.BillingAddress2 = "";
    request.BillingPostCode = "412";
    request.BillingCountry = "";
}

var result = objSagePay.ProcessDirectPaymentRequest(request, "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspdirect-register.vsp");
```

When the result object call is executed, I get Object reference is Null.

Any idea where i am doing things wrong?

**Stack Trace**

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>      SagePay.IntegrationKit.SagePayIntegration.GetPropertyTextValue(Object request, String propertyName) in C:\dev\dotnet\VspDotNetKitAPI\SagePayIntegration.cs:93
>      SagePay.IntegrationKit.SagePayIntegration.ProcessDirectPaymentRequest(IDirectPayment paymentRequest, String directPaymentUrl) in C:\dev\dotnet\VspDotNetKitAPI\SagePayIntegration.cs:449
>      orders_payment_Default.btnProceedCreditCard_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Default.aspx.cs:93
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9692746
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3562

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I have edited the question and included the stack trace

Comment: Looks like you aren't setting enough properties. Can you also try setting the `VendorTxCode`? This is your order number for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't setting enough properties on your payment request so it is throwing the `NullReferenceException` when trying to build the request object internally.

You can check if you have set at least the minimum values by calling the `Validation` method:

```
var errors = objSagePay.Validation(SagePay.IntegrationKit.ProtocolMessage.DIRECT_PAYMENT,
    typeof(SagePay.IntegrationKit.Messages.IDirectPayment), 
    request, 
    SagePay.IntegrationKit.ProtocolVersion.V_300);
```

The errors object in this case will tell you that you are missing the following value:

> VendorTxCode

This is your transaction identifier, for example, an order number. It needs to be a unique value for every payment you make. If you set that value, the error should go away.

**Bonus**: If you get really stuck with the SagePay Integration Kit for .Net, you can see the source code for it in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/WiredUK/SagePay.IntegrationKit).

Comment: Thanks.. i needed to set quiet few more properties. once i did all the properties the error went away.

Comment: @leppie Haha you're more than welcome. Always thought it was crazy they didn't supply the code somewhere. I'm not far from Sage HQ, perhaps I should go ask :)

Comment: @DavidG I had to add support for `OK REPEATED` status. Ended up just adding `OK_REPEATED` to the enum and changed the endlessly copy/pasted to deal with that :D

Comment: @leppie Oh haha. Never had to deal with that fortunately. In fact, I haven't used this code for a couple of years. Feel free to submit a PR with the updates :)